# Angular Material Dialog -> afterClosed -> which button was pressed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material in my application and also Angular Material dialogs.
After closing a dialog either action A or action B should be executed depending on the button clicked:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
    // if close button was clicked do action A
    // if other button was clicked do action B
 })
```

Is there a possibility to detect which button was clicked in afterClosed method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can close the dialog with custom data. Like this:

in your dialog component:

```
@Component({/* ... */})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourDialog>) { }


  closeA() {
    this.closeDialog('A')
  }

  closeB() {
    this.closeDialog('B');
  }

  closeDialog(button: 'A' | 'B') {
    this.dialogRef.close(button);
  }
}
```

handle close like this:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result === 'A') {
    // handle A button close
  }

  if (result === 'B')
    // handle B button close
  }
});
```

And since `afterClosed()` is an observable, you can filter this stream to create a more declarative solution:

```
const closedA$ = dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(filter(result => result === 'A'));
const closedB$ = dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(filter(result => result === 'B'));

closedA$.subscribe( // handle A);
closedB$.subscribe( // handle B);
```

Answer (score 3):

The way that I currently using is to pass an string from dialog while closing like :

```
this.dialogRef.close('A or B or whatever');
```

and I use them outside like this :

```
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: any) => {
    if (resuld === 'A'){
      // if close button was clicked do action A
    } else if (resuld === 'B') {
      // if other button was clicked do action B
    }
 })
```